# Under what circumstances do the following two methods of binding a click event to a paragraph not behave the same:

Tags: jquery

Under what circumstances do the following two methods of binding a click event to a paragraph not behave the same:

```
$("p").live("click", function() { alert("p clicked") })
$("p").click(function(){ alert("p clicked") });
```

Answer (score 0):

the first one will fire alert even if you add `<p>` dynamically (*and if you still use on older version of jquery that has `.live()` support*)

and the second one will not fire alert on dynamically added `<p>`  element's (*if you bind click on page load*)

Answer (score 0):

Your second event will not trigger when new paragraph elements have been added to the DOM after the event has been setup. The live event will help trigger the click event even after new paragraph elements have been added.